# How to generate XSD from classes using jvnet maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Two questions

1. Where is the definitive guide web page/site?
2. Give an example of generating XSD from classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

[maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) does not support generation of schemas from Java classes. And I have no plans to develop this feature at the moment. Well, unless someone wants to sponsor it. Consider using [jaxb2-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-maven-plugin) which provides the `schemagen` functionality.

So:

1. See the [wiki](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki).
2. Not supported, no examples at the moment.